# Count based on unique subset of fields

Tags: unix, sorting, uniq

I have a text file that is structured as follows:

```
P,ABC,DEF
P,GHI,JKL
B,ABC,DEF
B,MNO,PQR
```

I want to get a count of how many times a line appears where fields 2 and 3 are the same while preserving field 1. So, the output would look something like this:

```
2,P,ABC,DEF
1,P,GHI,JKL
2,B,ABC,DEF
1,B,MNO,PQR
```

`uniq -c` won't work (as far as I know) because it can't separate by field. `sort -u -t, -k2,2 -k3,3` also won't work as it can't count (as far as I know) and the command as written will simply destroy the third line as a duplicate while leaving the first.

At the end of the day, what I need to be returned are lines 2 and 4 as fields 2 and 3 combined are unique. But, I need to preserve field 1 as it refers to which dataset (in the real world) fields 2 and 3 originate from. So, a solution that returns lines 2 and 4 is really what I need.

Accordingly, a solution as follows works as well:

```
P,GHI,JKL
B,MNO,PQR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your `sort` command, I can delegate `-u` to `uniq -u`, which allows me to use the `-f` option of `uniq`. This option ignores the given number of leading fields. You want to ignore the first field, so `-f1`. For this to work I need to translate each `,` to a blank and back:

```
<data sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3 | tr , ' ' | uniq -u -f1 | tr ' ' ,
```

While this works with your example dataset, it fails when there are blanks. This is because `uniq -f` recognizes a field as `[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*`. If there are blanks in your actual data then they will make `uniq` recognize more fields than you want.

To overcome this you need to translate actual blanks to non-blanks, perform `uniq`, then translate back. In the POSIX locale `[:blank:]` includes the space and the tab character only; in other locales it may include more.

The following command temporarily translates spaces to DC1 characters (device control 1, octal `021`) and tabs to DC2 (device control 2, octal `022`):

```
<data sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3 | tr ' \t,' '\021\022 ' | uniq -u -f1 | tr '\021\022 ' ' \t,'
```

It should work, if only the data contains no DC1 nor DC2.

Even [if your `tr` does not support multi-byte characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558/108618), the translation will not interfere with multi-byte characters of UTF-8 because the most significant bit in each byte in a multi-byte character in UTF-8 is always `1`, while for DC1 or DC2 it's `0`.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly.